# Gif make react refresh whole page over and over again

Tags: reactjs, laravel, gif

I have a part of page-div (weather oriented stuff) made in react (the rest is made with Laravel), which works perfect, until I add a background as gif (e.g. raining gif), then page refreshes over and over again, and over again - again..
Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't enough information to work with. Show us how you are adding the gif in the code.

Comment: Atm it's added via scss like this:
  background-image: url('public/images/snow.gif');
Div is selected via id...

Comment: Please add code - to question.

Comment: I'm new both to Laravel and to React and I am not sure which part of code you want me to put here..
If anyone knows where i should start tinkering with, that would be good enough, I'll find answer that way... (e.g. render() in foo.js...)

Comment: I made it work, thank you for participating :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by not setting a div's background to what i needed, but putting an `<img>` over it.